# How to have fields in a form pre-populate based on a drop-down menu selection using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I want the address fields to pre-populate from a previous address field IF the user selects a certain option from a drop down list. So for example, if someone selects "Yes-i have a mortgage" from the drop down list, then I want the address fields below this question to pre-populate with the address that was filled out before.

Right now we already have something similar, but with a checkbox. So if the checkbox is checked, then the fields pre-populate. However, I can't figure out the JQuery to make this work for a selected value in a drop down. I'm very new to JQuery and coding in general so any help would be appreciated (and also if you could please do step by step instructions that would help me learn and understand better!)

Here is the JQuery for the checkbox that we currently have:

```
 function sameAsAbove(){
    if ($('#sameas').is(":checked")) {
      $("#application_coAddress").val("<%= @application.address %>");
      $("#application_coPostalCode").val("<%= @application.postalCode %>");
      $("#application_coCity").val("<%= @application.city %>");
      $("#application_coProvince").val("<%= @application.province %>");
    } else {
      $("#application_coAddress").val('');
      $("#application_coPostalCode").val('');
      $("#application_coCity").val('');
      $("#application_coProvince").val('');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
        $("#application_coAddress").val("<%= @application.address %>");
        $("#application_coPostalCode").val("<%= @application.postalCode %>");
        $("#application_coCity").val("<%= @application.city %>");
        $("#application_coProvince").val("<%= @application.province %>");
    }
});
```